# PKCS11 does not recognize new slot created in softhsm in runtime

Tags: spring-boot, pkcs#11, softhsm, hardware-security-module, sunpkcs11

I have a piece of code to import key and certificate into hsm using java. The problem is that when I run the java back-end to execute that api, it is ok when using the slots which were created before. However the problem here, when I create new slot at that time and try to execute the api for that slot, I received the message that show the slot id not found.

How do I achieve the result without re-running the code ? Here is what I am doing

```
public void importCertAndPk(String pin, String slotId, String alias, InputStream p12File) {
    Provider p = getProvider(slotId);
    // Load the key store
    KeyStore ks = getKeyStore(p, pin);
    BouncyCastleProvider provider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
    // Get pk and cert from p12 file
    KeyStore pkcs12KeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12", provider.getName());
    pkcs12KeyStore.load(p12File, System.getenv("P12_PASS").toCharArray());
    String pkcs12Alias = pkcs12KeyStore.aliases().nextElement();
    PrivateKey pk = (PrivateKey) pkcs12KeyStore.getKey(pkcs12Alias, null);
    Certificate[] chain = pkcs12KeyStore.getCertificateChain(pkcs12Alias);
    ks.setKeyEntry(alias, pk, pin.toCharArray(), chain);
}
```

When I re-run the back-end code again, it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look at [PKCS#11 specification](http://docs.oasis-open.org/pkcs11/pkcs11-base/v2.40/os/pkcs11-base-v2.40-os.html#_Toc416959741) section 5.5:

> Furthermore, the set of slots accessible through a Cryptoki library is
> checked at the time that C_GetSlotList, for list length prediction
> (NULL pSlotList argument) is called. If an application calls
> C_GetSlotList with a non-NULL pSlotList, and then the user adds or
> removes a hardware device, the changed slot list will only be visible
> and effective if C_GetSlotList is called again with NULL

You must re-query slot's list.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'm using java iaik package to interact with this. However, when I see the code inside, I see getSlotList method only has this one.                             
       try {
            slotIDs = this.pkcs11Module.C_GetSlotList(tokenPresent);
        } catch (PKCS11Exception var5) {
            throw new iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Exception(var5);
        }

Comment: Maybe there are exist another way and/or method to query slots list. Try to dive inside pkcs11Module.C_GetSlotList() for details.